# Gradle build - if then else possible

Tags: android, gradle

In an open source library of mine, I use something like following:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion setup.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion setup.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion setup.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion setup.targetSdk
    }
}
```

I don't want to force everyone to define those constants, but I want to use them and I use the same constants in all my projects and libraries. So I want to be able to use one code that works for me and for everyone else not defining those variables. I'm looking for something like following:

```
android {

    // pseudo code line
    if setup is defined 
    {
        compileSdkVersion setup.compileSdk
        buildToolsVersion setup.buildTools

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion setup.minSdk
            targetSdkVersion setup.targetSdk
        }
    }
    // default setup, if the user did not define global constants
    else
    {

        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 24
        }
    }
}
```

Is something like that possible? Any alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that your *setup* variable is stored in project extension

```
project.ext.setup = setup
```

This way, it can be accessible from your project and  all your subprojects

You can test the existence of setup like this

```
if (project.hasProperty('setup'))
```

The idea is to create a default *setup* var if no one is provided

```
if (!project.hasProperty('setup')){
    project.ext.setup = new Setup()
    project.setup.compileSdk = 24
    project.setup.buildTools = "24.0.2"
    project.setup.minSdk = 16
    project.setup.targetSdk = 24
}


android {
 compileSdkVersion project.setup.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion project.setup.buildTools

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion project.setup.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion project.setup.targetSdk
    }
}
```

Comment: `new Setup()` => this line does not work. I did not need it yet, now I want to define a user variable as well with this method. any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: I wrote "new Setup()", but this is your own class. I don't know how you've defined it.

Comment: I think this is not necessary at all. Seems like following works: `if (!project.hasProperty('versions.supportLib'))
    {
        versions.supportLib = "25.0.0";
    }` No need for "creating" the setup before...

Comment: You might have a look to this : http://mrhaki.blogspot.fr/2016/02/gradle-goodness-create-objects-with-dsl.html and this https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html. It may not be related to your problem but it might be interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I've tried this and it built successfully.

```
android{
...
    if (someCondition){
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
        ...
    }else {
        compileSdkVersion 24
        buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
        ...
    }
}
```